# Найти все смежные пары равных элементов вектора

Tags: c++, алгоритм, vector, stl

Количество элементов вектора в два раза больше задаваемого n.При моем довольно прямолинейном способе итератор  выходит за конец вектора.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    std::vector<int> v;
        int n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    int el;
    n *= 2;
    while (n)
    {
        std::cin >> el;
        v.push_back(el);
        n--;
    }
     std::vector<int>::iterator result;
     auto beg = v.begin();
     result = std::adjacent_find(beg, v.end());


     if ((result != v.end())) {
         while (result != v.end() && beg < v.end()) {

             result = std::adjacent_find(beg, v.end());
            auto  dis = std::distance(beg, result) + 1;
             std::cout << dis;
                 beg += dis;


             system("pause");
         }
         }

     else std::cout << 0;




}
```

Comment: Разумеется, выходит. Вы даже после безуспешного поиска делаете `beg += dis;`. Вот он и выходит.

Comment: @AnT Точно, спасибо. Сижу думаю, а самую очевидную вещь не приметил.

Comment: Глаза мои на лоб. Кто так пишет? Считайте n (типа size_t, а не int) . Потом объявите массив заданного размера std::vector<int> v(2 * n). Потом в цикле читайте v[i], а лучше https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for. Зачем в if проверка, которая в следующей строке будет проверяться в while? Ошибка в последней итерации. beg += dis выходит.

Comment: Я понимаю, что ошибка  в этой строке, но не знаю, как в данном случае сделать иначе.За советы спасибо, а по поводу if - забыл убрать после проверки.